# How to set multiple value in select box using grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am using grails 2.1.1. I have a table named audit firm. There are two types of firm. Audit review firm and ca firm. I am saving the value of audit review firm in parent table and ca firm in child table that's why ca firm is a multiple select box. But when I want to edit the audit review firm is selected but ca firms are not selected in the multiple select box. I have searched for it and applied some things but no luck. Can anyone please help me on this please ??!!! Here are my attempts below ::

my parent domain >>>

```
    class DistrictAssignToAuditReviewFirm {
    static mapping = {
        table('ADT_DIST_ASSN_TO_ADT_RV_FIRM')
        version(false)

        caFirm cascade: 'all'
    }

    AuditFirm auditReviewFirm

    long CREATED_BY=0
    Date CREATED_DATE=new Date()
    long UPDATED_BY=0
    Date UPDATED_DATE=new Date()

    static hasMany = [caFirm: DistrictAssignToAuditReviewFirmDetails]


    static constraints = {
        auditReviewFirm(nullable: false, blank: false)

        CREATED_BY(nullable:true)
        CREATED_DATE(nullable:true)
        UPDATED_BY(nullable: true)
        UPDATED_DATE(nullable: true)
    }
    String toString(){
        return auditReviewFirm
    }
}
```

my child domain >>>

```
    class DistrictAssignToAuditReviewFirmDetails {
    static mapping = {
        table('ADT_DIST_ASSN_TO_ADT_RV_DETL')
        version(false)
    }

    AuditFirm caFirmDetails
    DistrictAssignToAuditReviewFirm distAssnToAdtRevFirm

    static constraints = {
        caFirmDetails(nullable: false, blank: false)
        distAssnToAdtRevFirm(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
    String toString(){
        return caFirmDetails
    }
}
```

my view page >>>

```
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="auditReviewFirm">
            <g:message code="dl" default="Audit Review Firm" />
        </label>
        <g:select id="auditReviewFirm" name="auditReviewFirm.id" from="${auditReviewFirm}" optionValue="auditFirmName" optionKey="id" noSelection="['':'Select One']" required="" value="${districtAssignToAuditReviewFirmInstance?.auditReviewFirm?.id}" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="caFirm">
            <g:message code="dl" default="CA Firm" />
        </label>
        <g:select id="caFirm" name="caFirm.id" from="${caFirm}" optionValue="auditFirmName" optionKey="id" multiple="true" required="" value="${districtAssignToAuditReviewFirmInstance?.caFirm?.caFirmDetails?.id}" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont you think specifiying the data type of `${caFirm}` , `${auditReviewFirm}` and `AuditFirm` is important?

Comment: they are foreign key or an instance of table. if you think so then what to do ?